# DiscordJS error while deleting array of messages

Tags: javascript, node.js

My code:

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");

module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {
    const amount = args[0]
    if (!amount) return message.reply('Must specify an amount to delete!');
    message.channel.fetchMessages({
        limit: amount,
    }).then((messages) => {
        message.delete(messages).catch(error => console.log(error.stack));
    });
    message.delete().catch(O_o => { });
}

module.exports.help = {
    name: "clear"
}
```

Problem: I'm running the bot on my account and trying to make it delete messages on a command execution.
Errors: DiscordAPIError: Unknown Message
    at item.request.gen.end (C:\Users\brian\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\rest\RequestHandlers\Sequential.js:79:15)
    at then (C:\Users\brian\node_modules\snekfetch\src\index.js:215:21)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `message.delete` expects a number for timeout and not the array of messages

[Read documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=delete)

You might want to do something like

```
.then((messages) => {
        Promise.all(messages.map(msg => msg.delete()))
        .then(() => message.delete()) //delete original message after others are cleared
        .catch(error => console.log(error.stack));
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, but now i get a error like this one: DiscordAPIError: Cannot execute action on a DM channel

Comment: I think the messages retrived also has messages from other users ? and maybe the bot cannot delete that ? I am just speculating here

Comment: Yes is there a way to only delete messages sent by yourself and ignore other users?

Comment: Check the message. Author?